I have some animated 3D objects (Entities) inside a volume how can I synchronize their animation between users when the app is shared with SharePlay?
I am developing an application to experiment with SharePlay and how it works. Currently I would like to be able to share a volume and its content between the users (I am talking about visionOS).
I managed to share the volume and that was not a problem, but I noticed that if one or more objects (inside the scene loaded in the volume) have an animation associated to it (using Reality Composer Pro to associate it and Swift to play it) the animation is not synchronized between all the users, sometimes even stopping for those who joined the SharePlay session.
I know that the GroupActivities API allows the participants of a session to exchange messages, and I think that it would be possible to communicate the timeframe of the animation to the joining participants in order to sync the animations, what I was wondering is: is there was any kind of other method to achieve the same result (syncing the animations) without a constant exchange of messages among the participants?
My project consists in a volumetric window (WindowGroup with .windowstyle set to .volumetric ) that contains a RealityView in which I load a entity from a Reality Composer Pro package.
WindowGroup:
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(appModel)
        }
        .windowStyle(.volumetric)

ContentView:
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            // Add the initial RealityKit content
            if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Room", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
                content.add(scene)
                
                if #available(visionOS 2.0, *) {
                    findAndPlayAnimation(room: scene)
                }
            }
        }
        .task(observeGroupActivity)

        ShareLink(
            item: VolumeTogetherActivity(),
            preview: SharePreview("Volume Together!")
        ).hidden()
    }

findAndPlayAnimation is the function that finds the animation components inside of the scene and play them.
What I was hoping to see as a result was the synchronization of the animations between all the participants that took part in the SharePlay session, which is not happening. I suppose that sending a message (always using the GroupActivities API) containing the timeframe of the animation, its duration and if it is playing (taking as a reference the animation of the participants who has created the session) could help me solve the problem, but it wouldn't guarantee the synchronization in case the messages get delayed somehow.
